# CSS Animations and what the timings do

Tags: css, css-animations

```
.fromRight.box{
    -webkit-animation: fromRightbox 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -moz-animation: fromRightbox 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -o-animation: fromRightbox 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -ms-animation: fromRightbox 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    animation: fromRightbox 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fromRightbox {
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fromRightbox {
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fromRightbox {
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fromRightbox {
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
}
```

I was wondering if someone could explain the `animation: fromRightbox 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;` lines to me because I'm trying to understand what the `0.6s ease-in` means and what exactly `0.8 both` means too.

Thanks

Comment: You have all that stuff in [W3C](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-animations/) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`0.6s` = Animation Duration** *The animation-duration CSS property specifies the length of time that an animation should take to complete one cycle.*

**`ease-in` = Animation Timing function** *The CSS animation-timing-function property specifies how a CSS animation should progress over the duration of each cycle.*

**`both` = Animation Fill mode** *The animation-fill-mode CSS property specifies how a CSS animation should apply styles to its target before and after it is executing.*

**Animation Delay** *The animation-delay CSS property specifies when the animation should start. This lets the animation sequence begin some time after it's applied to an element.*

These resources will help you find out more

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-animations/ 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

Comment: Thanks for that information. `0.8s` would be the **Animation Delay**?

Comment: @Donald The animation-delay CSS property specifies when the animation should start. This lets the animation sequence begin some time after it's applied to an element.